# how to concatenate multiple rows into one

Tags: sql-server-2008, output, concatenation

Using SQL 2008 R2
I have two tables and want to create a table like:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI6mR.png)

Input tables
[input table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpkFg.png)

[inout table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqa3m.png)

I have tried using stuff function as

```
SELECT o.DEPT_ID,o.CLIENT_ID,
       code,
       (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + CODE AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
         FROM ORDERS
         WHERE (o.FUNDER_ID = f.FUNDER_ID) 
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS funder_code
FROM FUNDERS f
join ORDERS o on o.FUNDER_ID=f.FUNDER_ID 
where o.DEPT_ID=111 and CLIENT_ID='B001'
```

and I'm not getting the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your desired output appears to have the 'name' column from your second input table as a comma-separated list, but your code implies that you want the 'code' column concatenated instead. This solution concatenates the 'name' column.

Second, looking at your input tables, you can't directly use `join ORDERS o on o.FUNDER_ID=f.FUNDER_ID` because 'B0000000019' does not equal 'F19'. However, once you manipulate those columns so they could be joined, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.dept_id, o.client_id
    ,(STUFF((SELECT distinct CAST(', ' + name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
         FROM FUNDERS f
         JOIN ORDERS o2 ON o2.funder_id = f.funder_id
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS funder_code
FROM ORDERS o
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. It worked.